# Wordpress REST API Performance

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently using one website on a server to host a bunch of categorized posts and accessing those posts from hundreds of other websites which reside on the same server using the WordPress REST API.

From a performance perspective, I am looking to move that website to the same server as the hundreds of other websites to cut down on response time.  I am also utilizing transient caching to reduce calls.

However, is there a faster way to make same server calls to a domain or another workaround to increase performance?  Basically, if my websites are calling out to a domain that resides on the same server, does that still add more lag since it has to resolve the domain name each time?  I am just trying to see what kind of performance tweaks I can make using the REST API in WordPress to grab content from one master posts site and feed it to my other websites and reduce the amount of time being spent with all those requests.